# Content hides under fixed positioned div

Tags: html, css

Here is the code:

```
    <body style="margin: 0; background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #001f1f; font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif; font-size: 15px; background-image:url('img/2.png');">

<div style="width: 100%; height: 20px; position: fixed; background-color: #001f1f; text-align: right; color: #ffffff; padding-right: 100px;"><span style="float: left;">Search</span>View your shopping cart</div>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100px; margin-top: 20px; position: fixed; background-color: #f1f1f1; box-shadow: 0px 3px 3px #c9c9c9;"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" style="float:left;"></a></div>

Text example
```

What should I change that "Text example" wouldn't be behing those fixed div's?

Comment: use padding-top: 140px to body tag

Comment: There is nothing wrong to test styles within the attribute `style`, but it makes the code more unreadable for us. Also a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) example fits perfectly in this type of question.

Comment: Tamil Selvan, then all page content is padded 140px from top, even those fixed divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/k7um4/

`position: fixed` moves the elements out of the flow. So they don't have any effect on the following elements in the DOM's position. While your first div's have height they don't take up any real space in the flow - and your "text example" is just sliding up to fill the space they left behind.

In order for the elements to be seen you need to accommodate for the space they would have occupied by adding padding to the container element (your body). I've added a fiddle and also specified a `top: 0px` on both elements (if you're fixing and element, you probably want to specify your top/left positions.)

Comment: When you add anchors into the mix, the browser scrolls the page to hide the anchor under the fixed floating div.  Is there anything that can be done to handle that ?